# Spring 3.0 MVC client validation

Tags: spring-mvc, validation

I want to know what is the best way to validate a submition of an html form with Spring 3.0.
The validations are simple mandatory checks, not very business oriented.
I'm currently using spring-modules-validator + commons-validator, but it's maven dep. is with Spring 2.0 , not 3.0.  I'm not using annotations.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that you're not currently using annotations.  If you're open to using them, I recommend the new bean validation API (JSR 303).  Hibernate provides an [implementation](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html), and Spring 3.0 supports it.  The annotations provided in javax.validation cover most basic single-field validation, and you can apply them to any POJO (not just form beans or model instances).

Answer (score 2):

In Spring 3 the *best* way to go *is* to use annotations, if you can switch. The integration with the bean validation API makes it easy to add validation. All you have to do to validate a form bean is to add the @Valid (see "5.7.4.1 Triggering @Controller Input Validation" in the Spring MVC docs chapter "5. Validation, Data Binding, and Type Conversion") annotation to a controller method argument. Spring will then validate the bean and put the validation errors into a BindingResult for you.

```
@Controller
public class RegisterFormController {
  ...
  @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String submitFormHandler(@ModelAttribute("registration") @Valid User user, BindingResult errors) {
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
      // send user back to form view
    } else {
      // handle form submission
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

The docs say that Spring will automatically set up the bean validation factories and validators, but if that doesn't work for you, you can manually configure it very easily:

```
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
      <!-- Configures Spring MVC DataBinder instances -->
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
      <property name="validator" ref="validator" />
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <!-- Creates the JSR-303 Validator -->
  <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
```

I also created a project based on the client-side implementation of "valang" validation from the validation Spring Module that can provide client-side validation in JavaScript based on the JSR-303 and Hibernate Validator validation annotations.

http://kenai.com/projects/jsr303js

The project provides a taglib/JavaScript file that you include to put the main JavaScript code into the page, then another tag that you put somewhere in your Spring `<form:form></form:form>` tag to trigger the validation.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="jsr303js" uri="http://kenai.com/projects/jsr303js/" %>
  ...
  <head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/js/jsr303js-codebase.js"/>"></script>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <form:form name="regForm" commandName="registration" method="post">
      ...
      <jsr303js:validate commandName="registration"/>
      ...
      </form:form>
```